# Tratamento de dropdown html para muitos options

Tags: php, html, jquery, dropdown, jquery-select2

Possuo um dropdown que é alimentado em PHP consultando uma base de dados Oracle. Ele está funcionando normalmente, porém a quantidade que ele retorna é de 15000 registros e cada registro é um option no dropdown. Isso faz o mesmo ficar lento e acaba ficando inutilizavel assim.

Exemplo simplificado:

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="classificacao_fiscal">
   <option value=""> Selecione uma classificação fiscal </option>
   <option value="1">Classificação 1</option>
   <option value="2">Classificação 2</option>
   <option value="3">Classificação 3</option>
   <option value="4">Classificação 4</option>
   <option value="5">Classificação 5</option>
   ...
   <option value="14999">Classificação 14999</option>
   <option value="15000">Classificação 15000</option>
</select>
```

Existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso? Existe algum componente capaz de "paginar", ou seja, conforme vou rolando o dropdown, ele vai trazendo os próximos registros?

Estou utilizando como componente o [select2](https://select2.org/dropdown), onde o mesmo possui um searchbox para o usuário filtrar esses registros.

Comment: Acho que utilizar o select não é muito bom nesse caso, eu sugiro criar alguma outra solução para selecionar a classificação, algo como um modal. Mas se precisa usar select você poderia talvez utilizar o optgroup e agrupar itens por quantidade ex: Cada grupo manter 1000 registros. Mesmo assim ainda acho que o select não é uma boa opção. (Edit: lembrei agora que o optgroup não vai mudar nada com o select padrão do navegador...)

Comment: Faz um input onde o usuário irá digitar apenas o número.

Comment: Se é tudo repetitivo e só muda o número, não faz muito sentido criar um dropdown.

Comment: realmente, no caso de ser apenas números pode fazer um input com o tipo number e definir um min e um max para ele.

Comment: Eu utilizo este componente [Jquery Autocomplete com Ajax](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)

Comment: Desculpe se a minha pergunta não ficou claro, mas os options não vão ser somente números, são cadastráveis e cada um é diferente do outro.

Exemplo de options:
`<option value="212748"> Classificação de Nota X </option>
<option value="487891"> Classificação de SD </option>`

O usuário não saberá o número, somente a descrição que foi cadastrável.

Comment: @Alex Acabei mudando o componente para o que me passou, acabou resolvendo. Só fiquei curioso de como poderia manter o dropdown, se teria uma outra alternativa, mas enfim, coloca como resposta para dar como concluído, por favor, obrigado.